# Is historic downtown in Savannah, GA too loud for kids to stay over night?

Tags: hotels, children, georgia-usa

My wife and I are torn between booking a hotel by the historic downtown of Savannah for ease of transportation or somewhere a little further for quietness, so the kids can sleep. Given that the downtown area in some towns that we visit tends to be where loud music is played whereas some others are pretty much ghost towns after 10 PM.

For Savannah, GA is the historic downtown area considered to be loud and lively at night?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, Savannah's historic downtown is reasonably quiet much of the time, with a few exceptions during holidays, especially St. Patrick's day (week). Some later-night activity does happen, particularly along River Street, but hotels right there have rooms that don't face the river. Savannah is a very family-friendly town and there are many accommodations that are on low-key residential streets and squares.